# Vim: Avoid having to press ENTER after successful make?

Tags: vim, makefile, vim-quickfix

```
$ ls
Makefile          html-page/        page-generator.m4
Run               includes/
```

Alongside the `Makefile`, I have a script `Run` that is executed only when `make` completes without errors. This I've managed to implement with the following in my `.vimrc` file, which also looks for the `Makefile` in parent directories if needed.

```
" Before the 'make' quickfix command, run my quickfix pre-commands
autocmd QuickfixCmdPre make call MyQuickfixCmdPre()

" After the 'make' quickfix command, run my quickfix post-commands
autocmd QuickfixCmdPost make call MyQuickfixCmdPost()
```

and

```
function! MyQuickfixCmdPre()
    " Save current buffer, but only if it's been modified
    update

    " (h)ead of (p)ath of % (current buffer), i.e. path of current file
    let l:dir = expand('%:p:h')

    " Remove final / and smack a /Makefile on the end, glob gives empty if file doesn't exist
    while empty(glob(substitute(l:dir, '/$', '', '') . '/Makefile'))
        " There's no Makefile here. Are we at the root dir?
        if l:dir ==# "/"
            " Just use dir of current file then
            let l:dir = '.'
            break
        else
            " Try the parent dir. Get (h)ead of dir, i.e. remove rightmost dir name from it
            let l:dir = fnamemodify(l:dir, ':h')
        endif
    endwhile
    " Makefile is in this dir, so local-cd (only this window) to the dir
    execute "lcd " . l:dir
endfunction

function! MyQuickfixCmdPost()
    " Get number of valid quickfix entries, i.e. number of errors reported,
    " using filter to check the 'valid' flag
    let l:err_count = len(filter(getqflist(), 'v:val.valid'))

    if l:err_count ==# 0
        " The make succeeded. Execute the Run script expected in the same dir as Makefile
        call system('./Run')
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction
```

With this in place, after typing `:mak` in vim, the code is made and run... There are two possible results:

1. If there are errors during `make`, vim will present these errors with a `Press ENTER or type command to continue` afterwards, which is all good.
2. If `make` succeeds without errors, however, my `Run` script is executed, for testing my code (in this case an html file shown in a browser), but then when I switch back to vim, I have to press `enter` to get rid of a message from vim that I don't need to read because it doesn't tell me about errors. This message used to look like this:

```
"includes/m4includes/subs.m4" 34L, 759B written
:!make  2>&1| tee /var/folders/zk/0bsgbxne3pe5c86jsbgdt27f3333yd/T/vkbxFyd/255
m4 -I includes/m4includes page-generator.m4 >html-page/mypage.html
(1 of 1): m4 -I includes/m4includes page-generator.m4 >html-page/mypage.html
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

but after introducing the `redraw!` in `MyQuickfixCmdPost()` is now reduced to:

```
(1 of 1): m4 -I includes/m4includes page-generator.m4 >html-page/mypage.html
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

yet still with the need to press `enter`.

How do we avoid having to press `enter` every single time we return to vim after a successful compilation? Any ideas?

*Note: vim has a `-silent` command-line option, but as far as I can see this would silence all the `Press ENTER`s, and the goal here is to only avoid them after a successful `make`.*

Comment: Perhaps `silent call system…`? But i’m not sure this would actually do what you want. You could also feedkeys the carriage return in your function after the system call

Comment: Thanks so much Ben! You are right that silencing the system call wouldn't do it, because the `system` call is not what generates the message (it's the `make` itself that does). But `call feedkeys("\<CR>")` did it! I didn't know that function, so thanks for bringing it to my attention! Have a great week!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `call feedkeys("\<CR>")` afterwards. There are not many places you need `feedkeys()` (often `normal!` or similar commands will do), and there are subtle effects (look at the flags it takes carefully). Fortunately this is one place it is useful.